# log4j Warnings when running Eclipse Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to run an Eclipse Application from inside the Eclipse IDE. When trying to run `org.eclipse.cdt.GeneratePDOM` I **sometimes** experience the warnings on `log4j` and the application stops. My only solution to this problem is to delete the workspace and runtime directory and create them new. Then the application works for a while until the warning pops up again.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

There is no `log4j.properties` file in my project and there has never been one.

I want to get rid of the warning. Even if it turns out that it's not related to the Application stopping unexpectedly.

Comment: are you sure the reason of your app stopping is the log4j warning?

Comment: This is just a warning. I suspect the app is stopping for another reason.

Comment: maybe the app stops for another reason. Then the question is still about how to get rid of the warning.

Comment: "There is no log4j.properties file in my project and there has never been one.". So, it seems clear what you have to do in order to get rid of the warning

Comment: @aran Create an empty file log4j.properties?

Comment: It will still show the warning, since there's no valid appenders. Try the first example with the console appender (it's the typical base log4j file, which shows the logs on console): https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/